# Getting wrong results on modal windows with web2py

Tags: jquery, web2py

> Hi guys, what i want my code to do is to open a modal window everytime
>   i click a link which is a name and that modal window should open with
>   the details of that name but that is not happening!! Instead only one
>   link which is the first link can open the modal window but with the
>   wrong details, the details of the last name in the list. Other name
>   links do not open the modal window, i do not know what i'm doing
>   wrong! Here is the code below;
>
> I left out the CSS for the code

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
...............
................
...............
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#guardian').click(function() {
            //$(this).click(function(){

            var hiddenSection = $('#regDetails');
            hiddenSection.fadeIn()
                // unhide section.hidden
                .css({ 'display':'block' })
                // set to full screen
                .css({ width: $(window).width() + 'px', height: $(window).height() + 'px' })
                .css({ top:($(window).height() - hiddenSection.height())/2 + 'px',
                    left:($(window).width() - hiddenSection.width())/2 + 'px' })
                // greyed out background
                .css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)' })
                .appendTo('body');
                // console.log($(window).width() + ' - ' + $(window).height());
                $('img#close').click(function(){ $(hiddenSection).fadeOut(); });
            //});

        });
});
</script>


<div id="letterhead">
{{for head in head:}}

<div class="details">
<img width="220px" height="200px" src="{{=URL('download', args=head.school_logo)}}" style="border: solid white 2px; border-radius: 5px;"/><br />
</div>

<div class="details" style="padding-left: 10px;">
<h1>
    {{=head.school_name}}
</h1><br />
{{=head.Telephone}}<br />
{{=head.Fax}}<br/>
{{=head.Email}}<br />
    <h3>
        STUDENTS RESULTS MANAGEMENT SYSTEM (SRMS v1)
    </h3>
</div>
</div>
{{pass}}

<div id='container'>
<h3>
    SELECT STUDENT AND OR GUARDIAN VIEW THEIR PROFILE
</h3>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>STUDENT</th>
        <th>CLASS</th>
        <th>GUARDIAN</th>
    </tr>
    {{for student in student:}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{=A('view', _class="glyphicon glyphicon-user", _href=URL('student_profile', args=student.id))}} |
            {{=student.surname}} {{=student.name}}</td>
        <td>{{=student.class_name.class_name}}</td>
```

**THE LINK BELOW IS THE LINK THAT WHEN CLICKED SHOULD ESTABLISH THE MODAL WINDOW WITH THE RELEVANT DETAILS OF THAT NAME**

```
        <td><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="guardian">View | {{=student.guardian.surname}}</a></td>
        {{pass}}
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="regDetails">
<article class="popup">
    <a href="#"><img src="{{=URL('static', 'images/close.png')}}" style="width: 50px; position: absolute; top:0px;left:0px;" id="close"/></a>
    <div style="margin-left: 5px;">
    <center>
    <legend style="color: white;"><b>GUARDIAN DETAILS</b></legend>
        FULL NAMES: {{=student.guardian.surname}} {{=student.guardian.name}}<br />
        CONTACT DETAILS: {{=student.guardian.contact_number}}<br />
        <hr />
        <textarea rows="7" cols="40" id="message" placeholder="Notify Guardian Via Text Message" style="color: black; border: solid 1px white; border-radius: 5px;"></textarea><br />
        <hr />
        <button type="button" style="border: solid 1px white; border-radius: 5px;">Send</button><button type="button" id="clear" style="border: solid 1px white; border-radius: 5px;">Clear</button>
        </center>
        <script>
            jQuery('#clear').click(function(){
                document.getElementById('message').value='';
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    </article>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note, each HTML `id` attribute must be unique on the page. You cannot keep repeating the same `id` and expect the browser to know which you are referring to with each click. You should use unique `id`'s or maybe `data-*` attributes to identify each set of details.

Comment: Thanks Tony what u said worked, i changed my javascript & used a class tag instead of an id tag like this `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#guardian').click(function() {` but now the problem i'm faced with is that when i click the link name i still get the wrong details of the wrong name which for all link names they display the details of the last name in list of names in the modal window!!!

Comment: There should be some unique identifier for every link/details pair (maybe stored in `data-*` attributes of both the link and the details) -- when the link is clicked, grab its identifier and use it to identify the matching details.